# Extracting XML forming a resultset like format

Tags: xml, xmllint

I've encountered a case wherein I need to extract values from xml however, the tags are missing.  To elaborate, I've manually finger-counted around 5 of the same elements however, one sibling node(bigger brother) doesn't have the same element as the other bigger brothers do.  To put in example, please see xml below: (I used this previously, but I'll try to use this as an example)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="7/22/2019 4:18:27 PM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName="ADMIN-8DF005D47"
  DTS:CreatorName="ADMIN-8DF005D47\Administrator"
  DTS:DTSID="{8CCA1D42-642A-4932-AAEC-E02175A4B2DB}"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.2000.68"
  DTS:LocaleID="1033"
  DTS:ObjectName="HardestNestedWorkflow2"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:VersionBuild="12"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{FDD9B190-1A03-4A19-8794-FA86F4F46A93}">
  <DTS:Property
    DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:ConnectionManagers>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[ADMIN-8DF005D47.AdventureWorks]"
      DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"
      DTS:DTSID="{A32A68DF-3D53-4057-AF80-1B8D524F82BC}"
      DTS:ObjectName="ADMIN-8DF005D47.AdventureWorks">
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <DTS:ConnectionManager
          DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=ADMIN-8DF005D47;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-HardestNestedWorkflow2-{A32A68DF-3D53-4057-AF80-1B8D524F82BC}ADMIN-8DF005D47.AdventureWorks;Auto Translate=False;" />
      </DTS:ObjectData>

    <!--snipped-->

    </DTS:ConnectionManager>
  </DTS:ConnectionManagers>
</DTS:Executable>
```

so there's  (big brother) where there'll be siblings  (i'm looking for these elements).

Now, when I extract them using `xmllint` with `xpath`, only those siblings that are present get extracted.

The xml code might be a bad example but this is the format of what I'd like to achieve.  On the left column, it's the big brother node, the right one is the sibling nodes

```
DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"     {A32A68DF-3D53-4057-AF80-1B8D524F82BC}
DTS:CreationName="Excel"     {A32A68DF-3D53-4057-AF80-1B8D524F82BC}
DTS:CreationName="..."       <no value>
DTS:CreationName="blah blah" <no value>
```

Is there a way to write the `xmllint` `xpath` code to

1. Create the same format as above? Just like database result set.
2. Add an extra character in between brother and sibling nodes so I can pick it up using `awk`ie `DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"%{A32A68DF-3D53-4057-AF80-1B8D524F82BC}`
3. Instead of showing blank, just put `NULL` or any character that will alert me that the siblings are not present
4. Put the same brother node side by side if there is more than 1 sibling
   ie.

   big brother1%sibling1

   big brother1%sibling2

This will really help .  Looking forward to learning more of `xmllint`!

Comment: I've already tried the strategy of inserting one tag "in-between" the brother and the sibling node elements, and this was the code I used <big brother element> |  /*[local-name()='Executables']/@*[local-name()='CreatorComputerName'] | <sibling node element>;  so I'm chancing that I'd get a string of DTS:CreatorComputerName="ADMIN-8DF005D47" and I'll look this up using AWK but to no avail, this value only showed up once because i learned that pipe | stands for 'or' - please do correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Edit your post and include the actual `xpath` you need help with. If you hide it in the comments it won't get seen